# Как с помощью get запроса заполнить массив в реакт?

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть пустой массив и с помощью гет запроса надо его заполнить при загрузке страницы. Подскажите, как это сделать.

```
const url = 'https://localhost:44346'

useEffect(() => { fetch(url+'/all-books').then(res => res.json()).then(res => setBooks(res)) })
```

Получаю такую ошибку:

VM163:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: `useEffect(() => { fetch('...').then(res => res.json()).then(res => setArray(res)) })`

Comment: @entithat я обновил тему. подскажите, что не так.

Comment: `https:/...` возвращает json?

Comment: вы правы, это сервер виноват